# Window scrollY = 0 on Highcharts redraw()

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts 3.0.2

I have a div#chart and two js variables, `var options1 = {...}, options2 = {...}`. These contain distinct highcharts options (chart 1 and 2, let's say).

On document-ready, js calls `$('#chart).highcharts(options1)`. This **happily** generates chart 1.

I have a click event listener that calls `$('#chart').highcharts(options2)`.

When clicked, chart 2 is **happily** generated (replacing chart 1 in div#chart).

HOWEVER! When chart 2 is generated, **something resets the window.scrollY to zero**. In other words, if the user has scrolled down from the top of the page when clicking, then the window moves back to the top.

**What is causing this behavior, and how can I stop it?**

If I wanted it to look as if the page refreshed, I would have it refresh! AHHH!!!

**The Fiddle:** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buLkvta6/3/)

Comment: Can you add a JS Fiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: It's quite simple, let me explain: you create chart, which takes some space. Then you want to recreate that chart, so first, previous chart is destroyed. Site's height goes back to the initial one (where container for Highcharts is just empty div 0px x 0px), and this looks like scrolling page to the top. Solution? Just set height for the container in CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/buLkvta6/6/ - viola!

Comment: Thanks Pawel! This works, but in my case the page will incorporate some responsive width/height, so I need to leave the size of the chart flexible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the scroll position like this:

```
var tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
```

Then after changing your chart and page title, set it back:

```
$(window).scrollTop(tempScrollTop);
```

Here's the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/buLkvta6/5/)